# Duplicate entries into Elastic Search while logstash instance is running

Tags: logstash

I have been trying to send logs from logstash to elasticsearch.Suppose I am running a logstash instance and while it is running,I make a change to the file which the logstash instance is monitoring,then all the logs which have been previously saved in the elasticsearch are saved again,hence duplicates are formed.

Also,when the logstash instance is closed and is restarted again,the logs gets duplicated in the elasticsearch.

How do I counter this problem?
How to send only the newest added entry in the file from logstash to elasticsearch?
My logstash instance command is the following:
**bin/logstash -f logstash-complex.conf**

and the configuration file is this:

```
input
 {
  file
 {

     path => "/home/amith/Desktop/logstash-1.4.2/accesslog1"

  }
}

filter
 {
  if [path] =~ "access"
 {
    mutate 
{
 replace =>
 { "type" => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost 
    index => feb9
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question.

> when the logstash instance is closed and is restarted again,the logs gets duplicated in the elasticsearch.

So, it probably you have delete the .since_db. Please have a look at [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#sincedb_path). 
Try to specific the `since_db` and `start_position`. For example:

```
input
{
    file
    {
        path => "/home/amith/Desktop/logstash-1.4.2/accesslog1"
        start_position => "end"
        sincedb_path => /home/amith/Desktop/sincedb
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the file I have created is a new one where the start_position must be pointing to the beginning of the file?

Comment: It is still getting duplicated after making the above changes.

Comment: What OS do you use? There is a bug on logstash if you run on window. https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-429

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution.
I was opening the file,adding a record and saving it ,due to which logstash treated the same file as a different file each time I saved it as it registered different inode number for the same file.

The solution is to append a line to the file without opening the file but by running the following command.

**echo "the string you want to add to the file" >> filename**

Answer (score 1):

[ELK stack]
I wanted some custom configs in

```
/etc/logstash/conf.d/vagrant.conf
```

so the first step was to make a backup: `/etc/logstash/conf.d/vagrant.conf.bk`
This caused logstash to add 2 entries in elasticseach for each entry in `<file>.log;`
the same if i had 3 files in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf.*` in ES i had 8 entries for each line in `*.log`