# ELK Kibana shows every syslog event twice

Tags: logstash, kibana

I installed ELK by [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04) wonderfull guide.

I installed the Logstash-forwarder on a CentOS system and everything looks great.

The only problem is that every syslog event get written twice.
I tried to search for solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423991/duplicate-entries-into-elastic-search-while-logstash-instance-is-running) but i didn't made a service restart and I'm sure that linux knows how to write logs. (without changing inodes)

What else can i try?
All of my config files and app versions are the same in the guide

Comment: Make sure you don't have more than one elasticsearch output in your configuration files. Depending on how you're starting Logstash it's probably reading all files in /etc/logstash/conf.d. Any extra files there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

The logstash-forwarder service is [this one](http://logstashbook.com/code/4/logstash_forwarder_redhat_init).

I don't know why but when i run `service logstash-forwarder start` twice I don't get an alert `Job is already running`, It just start another process.

I verified by `ps -aux|grep logstash` and found:

```
root      6063  0.1  0.1 597956  5688 pts/1    Sl   21:17   0:00 /opt/logstash-forwarder/bin/logstash-forwarder -config /etc/logstash-forwarder -spool-size 100
```

and

```
root      6077  0.2  0.1 456704  5628 pts/1    Sl   21:18   0:00 /opt/logstash-forwarder/bin/logstash-forwarder -config /etc/logstash-forwarder -spool-size 100
```

When i run `service logstash-forwarder stop` both are stopped.
So I just start again and everything is fine now

Thank you all.